# node.js node-http-proxy not passing node modules

Tags: apache, node.js, http, socket.io

I want to pass /n/ requests to node.js and then leave everything else to Apache which is on port 8080. The proxy is running at port 80, and the code for /n/ is at port 9000.

However, node stuff like `socket.io` is broken because I don't think it is proxied correctly - the socket.io query returns a 404 from apache like expected:

404 Not Found

## Not Found

The requested URL /socket.io/socket.io.js was not found on this server.

---

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080

My starting HTML code for /n/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The proxy:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
io.set('log level', 1); 
app.listen(9000);

httpProxy.createServer({
router: {
    'localhost/n': '127.0.0.1:9000',
    'localhost': '127.0.0.1:8080'
    }

}).listen(80);
```

How can I get the proxy to pass `socket.io/socket.io.js` through Node, and not Apache? I have tried using the same code that serves my static files (eg css/js), but it seems that there is no actual folder called `socket.io` that exists - node seems to rewrite that.

Answer (score 0):

node.js alone will not do what apache will do out of box, to serve static file. so every url/request/file need to be specify in the router. to get it running quickly you can read express for node.js [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html)
or just put specify the file in router

```
    router: {
    'localhost/n': '127.0.0.1:9000',
    'localhost': '127.0.0.1:8080',
    '/socket.io/socket.io.js': 'path/to/the/file'
    }
```

Comment: where do I put path to the file? I can't see where the socket.io js is.

Comment: the problem is that socket.io is not a file but it is a node module